# Returning a vector<pair<string,string>> results in a crash in gcc compiled code (curlcpp)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, vector

I am encountering a strange intermittent crash in my gcc-compiled code with curlcpp. Here's the snippet -

```
catch (curl_easy_exception error) {
    // If you want to get the entire error stack we can do:
    curlcpp_traceback errors = error.get_traceback();
```

Just to clarify, curlcpp_traceback is a typedef to `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>` and `get_traceback` is returning a static vector by value.

The crash happens at the point of assignment and seems to result from a vector destruction. Here's the bt from gdb.

```
#0  0x00007f1d777c8418 in raise () from /root/ibm/shared/PIMGW1/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f1d777ca01a in abort () from /root/ibm/shared/PIMGW1/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f1d7780a72a in ?? () from /root/ibm/shared/PIMGW1/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f1d77816c18 in free () from /root/ibm/shared/PIMGW1/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000d1aa7b in deallocate (this=0x7f1d6c0c44c0, __p=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:110
#5  deallocate (__a=..., __n=<optimized out>, __p=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h:517
#6  _M_destroy (__size=<optimized out>, this=0x7f1d6c0c44c0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:185
#7  _M_dispose (this=0x7f1d6c0c44c0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:180
#8  ~basic_string (this=0x7f1d6c0c44c0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:543
#9  ~pair (this=0x7f1d6c0c44c0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:96
#10 _Destroy<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > (__pointer=<optimized out>)    at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:93
#11 __destroy<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*> (__last=<optimized out>,    __first=0x7f1d6c0c44c0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:103
#12 _Destroy<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*> (__last=<optimized out>,     __first=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:126
#13 _Destroy<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > (__last=0x7f1d6c12ffc0, __first=<optimized out>)    at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:151
#14 std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::~vector (this=0x7f1d71ad6350, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:424
```

The #15 in the bt is the assignment shown above.

It appears to indicate that a vector is being destroyed. This is probably the returned vector, so it isn't unnatural. What's unclear is why it crashes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does the crash persist in the debug build? if it does, can you debug it and check what actually happens?

Comment: Show a minimal example that can be used to reproduce the error. Otherwise it's hard to figure out what's going on under the hood from a couple of lines of code.

Comment: My educated guess would be heap corruption, likely in a remote, seemingly unrelated part of code. Heap corruption bugs are nasty this way.

Comment: @Igor, you may be right but it crashes in 2 different machines at the same point. It could be a coincidence and I have seen that before. Used Valgrind but it didn't drop any clues.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see from the source code (its [here](https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp/blob/687be1c252dce098f488ca8a46d847dac4972310/include/curl_exception.h), right?) copying is not protected by the corresponding mutex. So there can be a situation where `insert` triggers a memory reallocation whilst another thread is copying this vector, which leads to memory corruption.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought too. I assume the copy is not an atomic operation. It maps with why we see it more when the application threads using curl are more chatty.

Comment: Since I see this as the most likely explanation, I am marking it as the answer.

Comment: Based on the answer here, the problem has been solved in the curlcpp project - https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp/issues/100